# Program to view a files bytes

Tags: byte, file-format

There are some file formats that i am looking into, and in order to use them i want to understand them at the byte level.  I have been trying to find a program that displays the files bytes but the only ones i have so far only support displaying the bytes in hexadecimal. I would prefer them to be displayed in decimal instead of hexadecimal since the format i am looking at uses decimal.  I could write my own program to do this, however that would be less readable, and would take more time.  Currently all the programs i have found so far have displayed their output only in hexadecimal .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try HexEdit. It gives your the option to show Content as Integer-Values. (Property-Window):

[image: Overview and options]

You can download it from www.hexedit.com.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following works:

```
$ od -t u1 /bin/ls | head -5
0000000 127 069 076 070 001 002 001 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
0000020 000 002 000 002 000 000 000 001 000 001 015 192 000 000 000 052
0000040 000 000 103 092 000 000 000 000 000 052 000 032 000 006 000 040
0000060 000 023 000 021 000 000 000 006 000 000 000 052 000 001 000 052
0000100 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 192 000 000 000 192 000 000 000 005
```

I find it a bad idea, though, to look at it in decimal.

One should be able to mentally convert hexadecimal byte values to decimal or to ASCII characters if one dives into such matters.